# Scala: shorthand to import object Foo._ and trait Bar

Tags: scala, object, import, traits

Have a recurring situation, petty I know, but I'd like to consolidate the following:

```
import com.company.model.FooDAO
import com.company.model.FooForm._
```

into something like:

```
import com.company.model.{FooDAO, FooForm._}
```

the above 1-liner does not compile, however.

The best I've managed is:

```
import com.company.model.FooDAO, com.company.model.FooForm._
```

Scala being Scala, I assume the compact form above is possible...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write this:

```
import com.company.model.{FooDAO, FooForm}, FooForm._
```

Comment: +1, interesting, thanks, that's better than repeating the package name

Comment: That surprised me! I wonder if it's spec'ed that way, or if it works by implementation.

Comment: `import com.company.model.{FooDAO, FooForm}; import FooForm._` also works.